# Coldusion 8: transaction between Coldfusion cfm page and java object

Tags: java, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I would like to begin a transaction in a Coldfusion page, then create a Java object which does some business using data just inserted. The best would be to access the Coldfusion transaction. If this is not possible, I would like to flush the current transaction in Coldfusion so that I can access data inserted inside my Java object. See below template of the code I would like to achieve.

Best situation:

```
<cftransaction>
    <cfstoredproc procedure="insert_data" dataSource=#datasource#/>
    <cfset myJavaObjectWhichAccessDataInserted = CreatedObject("java","MyClass")>
</cftransaction>
```

**Problem with this is that I can't access the transaction of coldfusion inside my java object.**

Alternative:

```
<cftransaction>
     <cfstoredproc procedure="insert_data" dataSource=#datasource#/>
     <cftransaction action="commit"/>
</cftransaction>
<cfset myJavaObjectWhichAccessDataInserted = CreatedObject("java","MyClass")>
```

**Problem with this is that Coldfusion does not always flush changes to database, therefore the connection I create using directly JDBC driver in my Java object can't find data just inserted.**

What can I do?

Comment: Perhaps another option - [Interoperating with JSP pages and servlets](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-786c.html)

Comment: @Miguel-F I can't do that, I don't want to register any servlet in JRun (I would like to avoid additional configuration as much as possible).

Concerning the argument option, it is off topic for me. I want to use Java services and don't want to write them in Coldfusion, that's why I wrote a Java object.